# Degree in Philosophy at Mathematics department?

Tags: mathematics, degree, philosophy

I saw some tesis that, for me, look as paper of Mathematics and, indeed, are from mathematics' department. However, the name of the course is "degree in Philosophy".

There is any explanation about it?

I would imagine degree in Philosophy something about thinkers sociologics, human theory, etc.

Many thanks.

Comment: Was it "Doctor of Philosophy" by any chance?

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking, but a PhD, which is the normal doctorate for a mathematician is literally, Doctor of Philosophy. Math was traditionally one of the fields studied by philosophers, also including Rhetoric, etc.

Comment: @GoodDeeds, yes!

Comment: @Buffy, I understand... Where I studied were very different disciplines, but you're right.

Comment: From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctor_of_Philosophy): " In the context of the Doctor of Philosophy and other similarly titled degrees, the term "philosophy" does not refer to the field or academic discipline of philosophy, but is used in a broader sense in accordance with its original Greek meaning, which is "love of wisdom." "

Comment: One of my professors was on an airplane and was asked to help a passenger with a heart attack... he replied I can help with the engines I am a doctor of engineering... passenger survived though

Comment: @GoodDeeds, very good answer, thank you so much. I did not know that PhD had this meaning. In my region is different. Now I understand. Many thanks.